# TortoiseProc CruiseControl.NET: Unable to execute file problem

Tags: tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net, execute

I am new to CruiseControl and automated build. My problem is that the ccnet service always promt me "unable to execute file TortoiseProc.exe /command ...". My config file looks like this

TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:C:\Work\global.ad.lib.objectmanagement /closeonend:1

This command(tortoiseProc....) works well in a CMD window. The Ccnet service is execute with an Admin account. "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin" is in the environnement variables and can be executed from anywhere. If i force a build from the Dashboard, it builds perfectly. I have the feeling this is just a simple stupid thing...
Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify TortoiseProc.exe parameters separately from the executable name, inside "buildArgs" element. Here is the right ccnet.config fragment for your situation:

```
  <exec>
    <description>Execute TortoiseProc.exe</description>
    <baseDirectory>c:\path\to\tortoiseproc\folder</baseDirectory>
    <executable>TortoiseProc.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs>/command:update /path:C:\Work\global.ad.lib.objectmanagement /closeonend:1</buildArgs>
  </exec>
```

Also you can create cmd-file with your commands and use exec without parameters, if that would be easier for you.

Comment: Done, some other questions on their way